# jQuery - Bind Unbind click event depending of condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I need to disable the click event from a jQuery Mobile button depending if an array is empty or not. When the location loads I don't want the user to be able to click, but once the array has some values, I would like to change that.

This is what I have tried:

```
if (points.length != 0){ $('#addPlaces').bind('click');}
else{$('#addPlaces').unbind('click');}
```

I have also tried the same condition with:

```
$('#addPlaces').on('click');
$('#addPlaces').off('click');
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to disable the event? Doesn't disabling the button suffice based on points.length ?? That way, you need not  bother about binding and unbinding the event listener.

Comment: `$('#addPlaces').on('click');` does nothing, you need to specify an event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you wanna do that. Just return the event when the array is empty and continue with the execution otherwise.

```
$('#addPlaces').on('click', function() {

    if (points.length === 0) {
        return
    }
});
```

This way you need not keep toggling the event.